# How to serialize specific string property from list of structures using Join function?

Tags: string, vb.net, list, data-structures

I have a list of custom structures and I would like to serialize one specific property into one string, but I don't know how to use Join function properly in such a case?

```
 Structure structPerson
        Dim Name As String
        Dim Age As Integer
 End Structure


 Sub Main()

        Dim p1 As structPerson = New structPerson() With {.Name = "John", .Age = 20}
        Dim p2 As structPerson = New structPerson() With {.Name = "Samantha", .Age = 12}
        Dim persons As List(Of structPerson) = New List(Of structPerson) From {p1, p2}

        Dim strNames As String = persons.Join(", ", Function(p) p.Name)  'HOW TO JOIN NAMES OF ALL PERSONS IN LIST INTO ONE STRING?

        Debug.WriteLine(strNames)

 End Sub
```

I would like to get string "John, Samantha" as a result using Join function.

Thank you for your suggestions.

#JK

Comment: What you name your types is up to you but notice that none of the structures you use from the Framework have the "struct" prefix on the name? I'm not quite sure why people can use all the types from the Framework without issue but feel the need to denote their own types with such things. Given that you only have to mouse over a type or variable of that type in VS to see whether it's a class or structure, there seems little point.

Comment: I would really suggest using properties rather than fields for public data too. Sometimes it makes little difference but sometimes it does and fields are never better than properties, so sticking to properties every times means that you will never lose.

Comment: How do you mean "to use properties rather than fields"? Do you mean to use class instead of structure?

Comment: No, instead of `Dim Name As String` use `Public Property Name As String` (keeping in mind that auto-implemented properties are recent-ish in VB so they may not work if you're using an old version).  One reason for doing this is that even though that change is source-compatible, it's not binary-compatible, so if you need properties later (and there are a number of reasons why you might) it would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim strNames As String = String.Join(", ", persons.Select(Function(p) p.Name))
```

It's the shared `String.Join` method that you use to join numtiple `Strings` together with a separator between pairs. It will join any enumerable list of `Strings` or objects that will be converted to `Strings`. In the this case you use the LINQ function `Select` to get a list of `Name` values from your list of objects.

Comment: I tried to use your code, but when I run it, it throws exception (translated from Czech) :Object of type WhereSelectListIterator`2[test.Module1+structPerson,System.String] cannot be typed to System.String[]. ? #JK

Comment: @JaroslavKabrt, if only there was a way for us to know what the error message was. Hang one, maybe you could tell us! Certain overloads of `Join` were added later so, if you're using an older .NET version then you may need to use a different overload. There are other potential issues too if you are missing certain things but we shouldn't have to guess which it is. Most that I can think of would also cause a compilation error, not a run time exception. Maybe I made a mistake but I can't see what it would be and I don't know what I'm looking for if you don't provide all the relevant information.

Comment: Well, compilation (and build) finishes succeeded, but when I run, it throws exception:
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Objekt typu WhereSelectListIterator`2[test.Module1+structPerson,System.String] nelze přetypovat na typ System.String[].
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

p.s. My target .NET Framework is 3.5

Comment: That suggests that your version of .NET does not support that overload of `String.Join`. If you require a `String` array rather than an `IEnumerable(Of String)` then call `ToArray`, i.e. `persons.Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToArray()`. That said, I would have thought that that would be flagged at compile time, not run time. If you do as I say and it still doesn't work, please update your question with the current code.

Comment: Super, this really works:
`Dim strNames As String = String.Join(", ", persons.Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToArray())`

Thank You! #JK

Comment: The fact that you didn't see a compile-time error on that code makes me think that maybe you have `Option Strict Off`. If so, you should remedy that by turning it `On` in the project properties and the IDE options too, for future projects. That will prevent many data type mismatches sneaking through to run time.